# Writing raw JSON to CosmosDB and an Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to take the raw JSON body from an HTTP post and write it directly into my CosmosDB.

Let's say the data looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "123456",
  "storeName": "City Bar and Grille",
  "invoiceTotal": 65
}
```

However, the documentsOut.AddAsync command uses a format like this:

```
wait documentsOut.AddAsync(new
  {
    // create a random ID
    id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    body = sourceJson
  });
```

And then I end up with a document that looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "0e99d3ab-1956-4c0a-8ec1-99de5c987555",
  "body": {
    "id": "123456",
    "storeName": "City Bar and Grille",
    "invoiceTotal": 65
  }
}
```

What I really want is to end up with this:

```
{
  "id": "123456",
  "storeName": "City Bar and Grille",
  "invoiceTotal": 65
}
```

I'd like to drop the id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() completely (which should not be hard).

How can I pass the raw JSON through without needing to add it to some parent node (such as body)?

Comment: Why are you setting `body = sourceJson`? Have you tried just setting each individual property (e.g. `storeName = sourceJson.storeName`)? Same with ID: set it to `sourceJson.id` (although you have to ensure the id is unique within your partition). As written, you're creating a top-level property called `body` and setting it equal to the entirety of `sourceJson`, resulting in your document shape that you showed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to formalize my comment as an answer: You're specifically creating the `body` property of the Cosmos DB document you're creating:

```js
wait documentsOut.AddAsync(new
  {
    // create a random ID
    id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    body = sourceJson
  });
```

At the same time, you're ignoring the incoming ID. Since you wanted to preserve that ID, You can copy the ID over (as long as it remains unique within the partition) instead of generating a new GUID, and also grab individual properties from `sourceJson` to avoid the nested `body` element:

```js
wait documentsOut.AddAsync(new
  {
    id = sourceJson.id,
    storeName = sourceJson.storeName,
    invoiceTotal = sourceJson.invoiceTotal
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I was hoping I did NOT have to reproduce the object and could just save off the formatted JSON. I've implemented this now as a class as you've suggested and while not as simple as I had hoped, it gets the job done.

Comment: @DaveP - quite possibly, you could have also just passed `sourceJson` in as the parameter to `AddAsync()` but that would include the entirety of the payload, vs you being selective about it... (and also, the `id` parameter needs to be exactly `id` (lowercase) to match with Cosmos DB's `id` property)

Answer (score 0):

Using a similar example as shared by you in the question.
We can create a Model class with properties which want to store in database.

[image]

```
public class StoreDetails : TableEntity
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; } 
    [JsonProperty("storeName")]
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("invoiceTotal")]
    public string InvoiceTotal { get; set; }
}
```

Then can create object of model and pass that object to `AddAsync()`method. As shown in below screenshot.

[image]

```
        var item = new StoreDetails
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            StoreName = data.StoreName,
            InvoiceTotal = data.InvoiceTotal
        };
        await storeDetailOut.AddAsync(item);
```

and when we triggered post API, got response as shown below.

[image]

As finally we can see the same record is stored in CosmosDB.

[image]

Comment: *Please* don't post images of code/data/text - impossible to do anything with (or edit). See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why you need to use formatted text. Also: not sure what question you're answering. This is really a data modeling issue - the OP has no issue creating content (which your post explains how to do). And what I suggested in my comment covers it (and is essentially identical to the meat of your answer)